# Adjusting the location of a ggplot2 legend text generated using scale_colour_gradient2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using this code [example](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_gradient2.html)

```
require(ggplot2)
dsub <- subset(diamonds, x > 5 & x < 6 & y > 5 & y < 6)
dsub$diff <- with(dsub, sqrt(abs(x-y))* sign(x-y))
qplot(x, y, data=dsub, colour=diff)+scale_colour_gradient2("Scaled log(score)")
```

[image]

I'd like to adjust the legend text so it is middle justified rather than left justifed as in the figure.

Any idea?

BTW, adding:

```
theme(legend.text.align=0.5)
```

doesn't change anything

Comment: While I'm sure you could monkey around in the gtable object directly to do this, I haven't found anything that works as I expect it to aside from adding a line break to the title. `legend.title.align` does what I think you want, but only seems to have an effect for very short titles (try it with a legend title of just `"A"`). When the title text runs up against the edge of the bounding box, it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: There is an open issue which may be relevant here: [Using `margin` to adjust `legend.text`?](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1502). The same problem applied to `legend.title` when I tried (a while ago).

Comment: Using ggplot2 2.2.0, `theme(legend.text.align = 0.5)` works for me. The effect is subtle, but the labels are centred. Try `theme(legend.text.align = 1)` - the labels are right aligned.